# Sort two columns based on type Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sorting, pandas-groupby

I need to sort two Columns based on number and type

1. 881        x
2. 497        y
3. 2400       x
4. 2559    y
5. 2556    z
6. 1748    x
7. 443     y
8. 217     z
9. 1024    y

Current code snippet:

```
    import pandas as pd
    data1 = pd.read_csv('data/extracted.csv')
    data2 = data1.sort(['Result7d'], ascending=True)
    data2.to_csv('data/sorted.csv')
```

With this Type(x,y,z) is sorting, then how to sort individual category using pandas, Python?

Expected Outcome:

1. 881     x
2. 1784     x
3. 2400      x
4. 433 y
5. 497 z
6. 1024    x
7. 2559    y
8. 217     z
9. 2556    y

Comment: need `data2 = data1.sort_values(['Result7d', 'col1'], ascending=True)` ?

Comment: Prompt with a error:AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

Comment: Then use some old version of pandas, better upgrade.

Comment: I upgraded pandas to V.20, both columns are getting sorted, but first column is again sorting based on starting number like, 1784, 2400, 881...

Comment: Did the answer below work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = pd.read_csv('data/extracted.csv')
#data2 = data1.sort(['Result7d'], ascending=True)
# Use sort_values instead
data1['filenumber'] = data['file'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))
data2 = data1.sort_values(by=['type', 'filenumber'])
del data2['filenumber']
data2.to_csv('data/sorted.csv')
```

Comment: both columns are getting sorted, but first column is again sorting based on starting number like, 1784, 2400, 881...

Comment: Your first column is read as a string. Convert it to a numeric type field.

Comment: I have a file extension also after that numeric digit

Comment: like:
881.JPG   X

Comment: what does that "file" refers to ?

Comment: Name of your first column and 'type' refers to your 2nd column. I used arbitrary names because you didn't specify any.

Comment: File "test2.py", line 5
    data1['Result7d'] = data1['Result7d'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split(.)[0]))
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax,

>>pointing on apply()